# kurento webrtc video not displayed on heroku

Tags: heroku, websocket, webrtc, rtsp, kurento

have an app with a successfull kurento implementation connecting to a rstp://ip and displaying it to a video tag on my web page, just like this

```
http://www.kurento.org/blog/interoperating-webrtc-and-ip-cameras
https://github.com/lulop-k/kurento-rtsp2webrtc
```

it works like a charm on my localhost but once i deploy it to heroku and test it... well, it just does not display any video, no errors or weird issues it just does not display video, i'm not sure if there is something i missed to config on my kurento server like a cors config or similar and i've been looking for it with no luck so... any insight or guidance would be helpfull.

btw i have my kurento media server running on an amazon ec2 micro instance and my client running on heroku

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem!! I solved it using HTTPS instead of HTTP :)